# Javascript custom function with a check inside for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm probably really overcomplicating things...and it's difficult to explain so I'll just show the code here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        if (x[i].className === 'RU') {
            x[i].style.display = 'none';
            if (x[i].previousSibling.tagName === 'BR' && x[i].previousSibling.style.display != 'none') {
                x[i].previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    })(i);
}
```

That works fine but what I would like to do is create a function inside the loop that will check each `x[i].previousSibling` if they are of type 'BR'.  So I need to declare a function that will loop itself until it reaches an element which is not a 'BR' tag.  I tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        if (x[i].className === 'RU') {
            x[i].style.display = 'none';
            var check = true;
            var a = '';
            function foo() {
                while (check) {
                    if (x[i].previousSibling.tagName === 'BR' && x[i].previousSibling.style.display != 'none') {
                        x[i].previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
                        a = x[i].previousSibling;
                    }else
                        check = false;
                    foo();
                }
            }
        }
    })(i);
}
```

And that did nothing...I don't think it even got inside the `foo` function.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You are declaring a function there, but not executing it. That script will declare the function foo over the x.length and no more than that. 

Try declaring the funnction outside the for, and calling it after var a declaration, you can make the x and check, parameters for the function.  (not aware that coding trying to do).

Comment: @ecarrizo I guess I just needed a fresh set of eyes.  With a little modification I got what I wanted.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Post it as an answer and I'll mark correct.

Comment: lol! happens.. its okay, paste your working code as an answer and accept it :) (You can answer your own questions);

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked after some tweaking and getting rid of unnecessary variables:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        if (x[i].className === 'RU') {
            x[i].style.display = 'none';
            var a = x[i];
            foo();
            function foo() {
                if (a.previousSibling && a.previousSibling.tagName === 'BR' && x[i].previousSibling.style.display != 'none') {
                    x[i].previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
                    a = a.previousSibling;
                    foo();
                }
            }
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a `while` loop? `while (a.previousSibling && a.previousSibling.tagName === 'BR' && x[i].previousSibling.style.display != 'none') { x[i].previousSibling.style.display = 'none'; a = a.previousSibling; }` . Or even: `for (var a = x[i]; a.previousSibling && a.previousSibling.tagName === 'BR' && x[i].previousSibling.style.display != 'none'; a = a.previousSibling) { x[i].previousSibling.style.display = 'none'; }`

Comment: Prov: "More then one way to skin a cat" :)